# icon cannot be affected when hover

Tags: html, css, sass

When hover, I would like to translate an icon but `CSS` is not be effectible to it.

```css
#humberger {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#humberger div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 24px;
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#humberger div:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 0;
}

#humberger div:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

#humberger div:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: 0;
}

#humberger:hover {
  div:nth-of-type(1) {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  div:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  div:nth-of-type(3) {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="humberger">
  <div onclick='openNav()'></div>
  <div onclick='openNav()'></div>
  <div onclick='openNav()'></div>
</div>
<span class='icon-title'>Open</span>
```

I am expecting the translation like below.

[image]

If someone gave me any knowledge to solve this, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSS notation is not valid.

Try this structure instead:

```
#humberger:hover > div:nth-of-type(1){
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

(tested and works)

Answer (score 0):

Plz try this code..

**css**

```
#humberger div{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  height:4px;
  width: 24px;
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
}
#humberger:hover div {
  transition: 0.5s all ease 0s;
}
#humberger div:nth-of-type(1){
  top:0;
}
#humberger div:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 10px;
}
#humberger div:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom:0;
}
#humberger:hover div:nth-of-type(1){
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
}
#humberger:hover div:nth-of-type(2){
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
#humberger:hover  div:nth-of-type(3){
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment !
Thank for your code,  icon is transforming as i expected to.

Answer (score 0):

Add transition time & transition-origin and adjust the degree of rotation.

```css
#humberger div{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  height:4px;
  width: 24px;
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .2s; /*Add transition time*/
  transform-origin: 100% center; /*Add transform origin*/
}

#humberger:hover{

  div:nth-of-type(1){
    transform: rotate(-55deg); /*Adjust angle*/
  }

  div:nth-of-type(2){
    transform: translateX(100px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }

  div:nth-of-type(3){
    transform: rotate(55deg); /*Adjust angle*/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly follow the SASS Structure.

this is the SASS Code for your structure:

```
#humberger {
    position: relative;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    div{
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        height:4px;
        width: 24px;
        background-color: #444;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        &:nth-of-type(1){
            top:0;
        }
        &:nth-of-type(2) {
            top: 10px;
        }
        &:nth-of-type(3) {
            bottom:0;
        }
    }
    &:hover{
        div{
            &:nth-of-type(1){
                transform: rotate(45deg);
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                margin: auto;
            }
            &:nth-of-type(2){
                transform: translateX(100px);
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }
            &:nth-of-type(3){
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                margin: auto;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code snippet with normal css.

```css
#humberger {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#humberger div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 24px;
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
#humberger div:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 0;
}
#humberger div:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 10px;
}
#humberger div:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: 0;
}
#humberger:hover div:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
#humberger:hover div:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
          transform: translateX(100px);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
#humberger:hover div:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="humberger">
    <div onclick='openNav()'></div>
    <div onclick='openNav()'></div>
    <div onclick='openNav()'></div>
</div>
<span class='icon-title'>Open</span>
```

the above SASS code is work same like the Snippet.

I hope this answer will helpful to you.

Thank You...